# sybase format results to 4 decimal places

Tags: sybase

In sybase, how do you format the result from a select statement for a numeric field, to have no commas and 4 decimal digits.

For Example:

344,500.39495     =    344500.3949

492,930,948.39    = 492930948.3900

Answer (score 5):

You can convert and format a number or a float to string with the `str()` function.
The second parameter is the total length of the number, including the decimal point, and the third parameter is the length after decimal point.

```
str(yourDecimalNumber, 20, 4)
```

Comment: I would use `trim( str(yourDecimalNumber, 20, 4) )` to get rid of spaces

Answer (score 2):

You could use `ROUND ( numeric-expression, integer-expression )`

`numeric-expression` : The number, passed to the function, to be rounded.

`integer-expression` : A positive integer specifies the number of significant digits to the right of the decimal point at which to round. A negative expression specifies the number of significant digits to the left of the decimal point at which to round.